# Eclipse Can Export A Java File Into A .Jar File But Keeps Running Into Errors

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Basically, Eclipse cannot really export a java file that is executable. Whenever it is exported and opened as a .jar file, it would show the:

*'The JAVA Jar File Could Not Be Launched.
Check the console for possible error messages.'*

This is the code, ignore the '?' marks. They have actual texts and those are just substitutes.

```
private JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Firstone window = new Firstone();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Firstone() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(50, 50, 470, 100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("????");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(190, 40, 76, 29);
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("???");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(18, 18, 432, 16);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
}
```

}

I'm currently stuck on this process and already tried almost all the Youtube tutorials to forum posts but could not find the right solution for this.
The Computer is a MacBook and runs the version macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: _"Check the console for possible error messages."_ means that you should run it on the command line via `java -jar <file>.jar` and check for possible error messages. Please provide beside that error message not only code snippets, but a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please tell also what you get for `java -version`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, when trying to do the `java -jar <file>.jar`. Apparently, it worked after dragging the file into the Terminal after `java -jar` and didn't show up with any errors today. Tysm!